# Command to use guake under qt creator

Tags: 14.04, gnome, qt-creator, guake

I want to change default terminal in QT Creator from xterm to guake. I tried some stuff like usr/bin/guake -e and usr/bin/guake -e -n --show etc but it does not work. I will appreciateany sort of help[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `-n`?

```
/usr/bin/guake --new-tab -e
```

`-e` must be last argument, since Qt Creator will append its command at the end.